# The integral of $\Gamma\left(\zeta\right) \, W_{-\zeta,\mu}(z) $

Tags: reference-request, special-functions, hypergeometric-functions, gamma-function

Someone has a reference that addresses an integral of the followns  type 
 $$I_{a,b,x} = \int_{0}^{+\infty} \zeta^{-a} \, \Gamma\left(\zeta+b\right)  \, W_{-\zeta-b,\tfrac{-1}{2}}(x) \, d\zeta$$
where $\Gamma(.)$ is Euler's Gamma-function and $W_{\kappa,\mu}(x)$ is the Whittaker function, with $a,b>0$ and $x\in \mathbb R$.

Thanks you in advance